# android background activities for laying out views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

I need to load 30+ images to a page (with teaser text). I load all the images via an AsyncTask, but I can't modify the current layout because you can only perform modifications to a view on the main thread. What's the best way to load EVERYTHING asynchronously so that my app doesn't have to hang during a "page load" ?

Answer (score 0):

Why cannot modify layout? for `AsyncTask`, you have [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) that guarantees to run on UI Thread. You just need to call [publishProgress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29) in your `doInBackground` code.

==Update==

```
private class LoadImageTask<Url, String, String> extends AsynTask{
    doInBackground(Url... urls){
        for(int i=0; i<urls.length; i++){
            File img = DownloadImage(urls[i]); // Your download method.. 
            publishProgress(img.filename);     // Suppose it is saved in sd card
            // publish progress will call onProgressUpdate immediately, but on different thread
        }
    }

    onProgressUpdate(String filename){
        // Update the UI.. this method will run on UI thread
        displayImage(filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: will that still run asynchronously though? Or will it "pause" my main thread?

Comment: onProgressUpdate will pause, so only update UI with it. Loading is suppose to be done in doInBackground. Check my update answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can build a view in the background.  You're best bet would be to show a progress dialoge so the user understands why the app is busy.

Comment: Progress dialog will be blocked as well, if the task is not running on separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

If your class extends activity, you can use

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //Update UI elements in this block
    }  
});
```

Comment: it will run on the main thread as it will be queued. as for your thread that loads the images, it will still continue to run.